# Pandas Dataframe groupby year and find top item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have pandas dataframe in the following format:

```
d = {'item_code': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C'], 'year': ['2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

This is how my dataframe looks like:

```
    item_code   year
 0   A           2010
 1   B           2010
 2   C           2010
 3   A           2010
 4   A           2010
 5   B           2011
 6   B           2011
 7   A           2011
 8   C           2011
```

I have used groupby to list each year and its corresponding items.

```
df.groupby(['year', 'item_code']).size()
```

This is the result:

```
year  item_code
2010  A            3
      B            1
      C            1
2011  A            1
      B            2
      C            1
dtype: int64
```

I want to get the top items in a year. For example for the year 2010 the top item is A. Similarly, for year 2011 the top item is B. How can I get that?

And lets say I want to get the top N items for each year. How can I do that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) which sort each group by counts:

```
N = 2
df1 = df.groupby('year')['item_code'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().iloc[:N])
#alternative
#df1 = df.groupby('year')['item_code'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(N))
print (df1)
year   
2010  A    3
      B    1
2011  B    2
      A    1
Name: item_code, dtype: int64
```

Another solution with `groupby` + [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
N = 2
df1 = df.groupby(['year'])['item_code'].value_counts().groupby('year').head(N)
print (df1)
year  item_code
2010  A            3
      B            1
2011  B            2
      A            1
Name: item_code, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I didn't think you will think of dual groupby too!

Comment: I didn't know that we can dual groupby. Thanks a lot. Can you kindly tell me what kind of plot will be suitable for visualization of this type of data?

Comment: Do you think bar plot?

Comment: One possible solution is use `df1.unstack().plot.bar()`, but for each group should be different categories, so plot should be not very nice. `df1.unstack()` reshape output and add `NaN`s for missing categories.

Comment: hmmm, do you think `df1.unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)` ?

Comment: Yes that is what I am thinking about. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use dual `groupby` i.e

```
df.groupby(['year', 'item_code']).size().sort_values(ascending=False).groupby(level=0).head(1)

year  item_code
2010  A            3
2011  B            2
dtype: int64
```